# PyCaret methods on GPU/TPU

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, cpu, kaggle, pycaret

[image: CPU Utilization]

When I ran `best_model = compare_models()` there is a huge load on CPU memory, while my GPU is unutilized. How do I run the `setup()` or `compare_models()` on GPU?
Is there an in-built method in PyCaret?

Comment: PyCaret is not for deep learning. Can it leverage GPU?

Comment: For some methods, it can. But for most, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only some models can run on GPU, and they must be properly installed to use GPU. For example, for `xgboost`, you must install it with pip and have CUDA 10+ installed (or install a GPU `xgboost` version from anaconda, etc). Here is the list of estimators that can use GPU and their requirements: https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=gpu#pycaret-on-gpu

As Yatin said, you need to use `use_gpu=True` in `setup()`. Or you can specify it when creating an individual model, like `xgboost_gpu = create_model('xgboost', fold=3, tree_method='gpu_hist', gpu_id=0)`.

For installing CUDA, I like using Anaconda since it makes it easy, like `conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit`. It looks like for the non-boosted methods, you need to install cuML for GPU use.

Oh, and looks like pycaret can't use tune-sklearn with GPU (in the warnings [here](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/classification.html?highlight=tune-sklearn#pycaret.classification.tune_model) at the bottom of the `tune_model` doc section).

Answer (score 2):

To use gpu in PyCaret you have to simply pas use_gpu=True as parameter in setup function.
Example:
model = setup(data,target_variable,use_gpu=True)

Comment: Doesn't work with Kaggle. Tried this already and it is only using the RAM and the CPU, and not the GPU.

Comment: @LITDataScience possibly because the models that can use GPU are not compiled for it (e.g. xgboost should be installed with pip and CUDA 10+ needs to be installed). Here is the list and requirements: https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=gpu#pycaret-on-gpu